# Finding a specific element with Selenide (Selenium) using cssSelector

Tags: css, selenium-webdriver, element, selenide

[image: structure]

If there is a structure of elements like in the image,
it is possible to get out each static-property like:

```java
$$('#static-information .value').get(0)
```

or

```java
$$('.static-property .value').get(0)
```

But since each static property has a unique .key in that div - is it possible to use that key to get specific elements to make the selector more generic and more resistant to errors if order changes (get rid of using get(0), get(1) etc.).

E.g.

```java
investorFullName = $$('#static-information .key="Name" .value')
```

Or something like `td[class='key'][value='Name']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to find the static property by key, you need to use xpath, css selector not support find element by its text.

```
findPropertybyKey(key) {
   return element(by.xpath('//div[@class="key"][text()="' + key + '"]/..'));
}

readPropertyValuebyKey(key) {
   return findPropertybyKey(key).element(by.css('.value')).getText();
}
```

Comment: How to solve it if there are several class names in the tag to find. __class="value some"__? I do not think that would work then?